# USE ORBEON VIA PUBLIC DNS

Tags: orbeon

i configured a public dns through IIS to use ORBEON form loading through external connections. I am using the ajp13 connector. Unfortunately the orbeon module through the external address chosen (http://orbeonmodule.igcom.it/orbeon/fr) keeps telling me "Address not found". Could I get assistance in successfully configuring ORBEON for external connections? As for the local connection it works without problems (localhost:8080/orbeon/fr). The ORBEON module can be used directly by calling the form via the NEW/EDIT options (example: http://orbeonmodule.igcom.it/orbeon/fr/ARMONIA/VF_01/new?idpratica=2637&user=supervisore.s&modello=58a9db826033f7a63714a514fb923a.
I look forward to receiving your reply. thanks. Marco

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that:

1. Accessing `http://orbeonmodule.igcom.it/orbeon/fr`, you get an error "Address not found".
2. However accessing `http://orbeonmodule.igcom.it/orbeon/fr/ARMONIA/VF_01/new?idpratica=2637&user=supervisore.s&modello=58a9db826033f7a63714a514fb923a` is working for you.

If (2) works, then your DNS must be configured correctly, and Apache is able to forward requests to Tomcat, at least in some cases. As to why it wouldn't work in (1), I'd recommend you investigate where that "Address not found" message comes from:

- Is it an error at the browser level, who is unable to connect to the server? That seems unlikely since (2) works. But if this is the case, you should be able to see it with Chrome Dev Tools (or similar).
- Is it an error at the Apache level? Is it an error at the Tomcat / Orbeon Forms level? If so, you should be able to find more information about the error in the relevant log files.

(And once you find more, feel free to update your question with that information, and post a comment to answer.)

Comment: Meanwhile, thanks for the reply. My first doubt is about the definition of the connector on the "server.xml" file and on the "workers.properties" file. On the first file this is the definition: "<Connector protocol =" AJP / 1.3 "
               address = "::"
               port = "8080"
               redirectPort = "8443" /> ".

Comment: On the second file it is this:" worker.list = orbmodule
worker.orbmodule.port = 8009
worker.orbmodule.host = localhost
worker.orbmodule.type = ajp13
worker.orbmodule.lbfactor = 1 "But must the PORT parameter coincide with the port on which I have set ORBEON (in my case 8080)? Or must it be a different port (in the various examples found it was always 8009).

Comment: @Marco AJP uses a different port, so it must be different than your regular HTTP port (by default 8080). But if your situation is that things work for a given path (`/orbeon/fr`), but not another path (`/orbeon/fr/ARMONIA/VF_01/new?idpratica=2637&user=supervisore.s&modello=58a9db826033f7a63714a514fb923a`), I would think that the problem isn't at the Apache level. You'll let me know what else you find! -Alex

Comment: Hi, I finally solved. It was a folder permissions problem of the AJP connector and parameters were missing in the configuration of the file workers.properties. thanks anyway for the assistance. Marco

Comment: Perfect @Marco; I didn't expect that a configuration issue at the level of the AJP connector could cause requests to work for a given path, and not for another path, so I was wrong! But I'm glad you found the solution, and thank you for the update. -Alex